# Lanching the Spatial conditional autoregressiveCAR model in R with regions without links with the others

Tags: r, conditional-statements, spatial, autoregressive-models

I am a beginner in R. I would like to run the CAR model to test the correlation between two variables. The problem here is that the test can't be done because in the map there are two regions that are independent and without borders with the other regions. Any help?
Here is the code with the error

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\zaatour\\Desktop\\SVI')
SVI = read.csv("pasco2.csv")
SVI
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(spdep)
options(scipen = 999 )
map2 <- st_read("pasco.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(map2)
packages <- c("CARBayes", "sf", "tidycensus", "janitor", "tidyverse", "spData", "spdep")


miss_pkgs <- packages[!packages %in% installed.packages()[,1]]

if(length(miss_pkgs) > 0){
  install.packages(miss_pkgs)
}

invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))

rm(miss_pkgs, packages)
list.nb2 <- poly2nb(map, row.names = rownames(SVI)) #list of neighbours of each city
?poly2nb
list.nb2
?nb2mat
A <- nb2mat(list.nb2,style="B",zero.policy = TRUE )
A

#write.csv(A,"C:\\Users\\zaatour\\Desktop\\M.csv", row.names = FALSE)


model.hillsborough <- CARBayes::S.CARleroux(cases ~ SVI, data = SVI, W = A, family = "gaussian", burnin = 20000, n.sample = 100000, thin = 10)
model.hillsborough
```

I want to launch the code and exclude the regions without links